# How to integrate $[\tan(\theta)]^{63/97}$?

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

How to integrate $[\tan(\theta)]^{63/97}$? i.e. $$\int_{0}^{\pi/4}[{\tan(\theta)}]^{63/97}d\theta\,?$$ I am trying this question by taking $[\tan(\theta)]^{63/97}=u$. Therefore, $\tan(\theta)=u^{97/63}$. So, $$\sec^2(\theta)d\theta= (97/63)×u^{34/63}du.$$ So, $$d\theta= [(97/63)×u^{34/63}/(1+u^{194/63})]du.$$ So, the final integration will be $$(97/63)\int_{0}^{\pi/4} [u^{97/63}/(1+u^{194/63})]du.$$ But I don't know how to approach further. Please help me out.

Comment: You forgot to change the upper limit of integration.

Comment: Why not use $\tan \theta = v^{97}$ ?

Comment: $$\int_0^{\pi/4}\tan^\alpha xdx\overset{x=\arctan t}{=}\int_0^1\frac{t^\alpha(1-t^2)}{(1+t^2)(1-t^2)}dt\overset{x=t^4}{=}\int_0^1\frac{x^{\frac{\alpha-3}4}-x^{\frac{\alpha-1}4}}{4(1-x)}dx=\frac14\left(\psi\big(\frac{\alpha+3}4\big)-\psi\big(\frac{\alpha+1}4\big)\right)$$

Comment: by [] did you mean GIF?

Comment: No@HariShankar. It's just a third bracket.

Answer (score 4):

$$I_n=\int_0^{\frac \pi 4} \tan^a(\theta)\, d\theta=\int_0^1  \frac{u^a}{u^2+1}\,du$$
$$\frac{u^a}{u^2+1}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n u^{2n+a}\,du$$
$$I_n=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \int_0^1u^{2n+a}\,du=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n }{2 n+1+a}$$
$$I_n=\frac{1}{4} \left(\psi
   \left(\frac{a+3}{4}\right)-\psi
   \left(\frac{a+1}{4}\right)\right)$$

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, but what is $\psi$ here?

Comment: @NNN. The digamma function. It is also related to generalized harmonic numbers.